# How do I find the transaction ID of what I just transacted?

Tags: transactions, blockchain

If I send or receive something (with Bitcoin-QT), how can I get the transaction ID of that transaction?

context: I'm playing satoshi bones and they have verification code I can run to make sure they're playing by their own rules.  The game is based on a hash of the transaction ID of what I send them, so I just want to give it a check but I need the transaction IDs of my transactions with them.

verification code supplied by satoshi bones that I want to run:

```
import hashlib
import struct
def verify(txid,secret,lessthen):
   sha512 = hashlib.sha512()
   sha512.update(secret+txid)
   b = sha512.digest()
   result = struct.unpack("<H",b[0]+b[1])[0]
   if result<lessthen:
      print "win!"
   else:
      print "lose!"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With bitcoin-qt you can look in your transaction history and right click your transaction to find more info, including the txid.

When using bitcoind, the client gives you the txid as the response for a successful send.

Answer (score 0):

So simple. What you have to do is to get the wallet address of the person you transferred to and visit blockchain.info, then click on home and you will see the a  search box, paste  the wallet address there paste and on the next page you will see long string of characters with oldest has at the top. immediately of that copy the long string character that is all. Read here http://www.guruscrib.net/bitcoin-create-bitcoin-wallet-blockchain-info/

Comment: You probably mean "newest at the top" not oldest? Otherwise the instructions wouldn't make sense.